# An issues with running "pip install Beautifulsoup" on cmd

Tags: python-3.x, installation, beautifulsoup

Been struggling with this. since I tried to run "pip install beautifulsoup" on cmd it refuses to run.
Theses are the steps taken so far.

1. Dowloaded pip via get-pip.py
2. After typing " >py " on cmd it shows the current version
3. This is where i get stuck

> cd desktop is not recognized as seen in the snip below
> [screenshot of response from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqL4d.png)

4. It seems to persist after trying different things and commands

Please any one who has experienced this before should please help.

Answer (score 2):

you can try:

1st way:install the BeautifulSoup package using pip

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

2nd way: using easy_install

```
easy_install beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue because the package name is actually `beautifulsoup4`.

Just run `pip install beautifulsoup4` and you should be good to go.